# Pass html input into a js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, addeventlistener

I would prefer to accomplish this without inline script. I'd be interested to learn this both with and without jQuery.

After trying several different element selector methods, changing the placement of my script tag, and trying onclick, this is how my code looks.

The console is returning the error "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".

javascript:

```
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", someFunction(document.getElementById("number").value));

someFunction(){};
```

Html:

```
<head>
    <script src="nibble.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" id="number" name="number" ></input>
        <input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="Test number"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is because your document.getElementById("button") is null when it is getting executed. FIrst wait for the page to be loaded and then trigger your event handlers

Comment: How would I wait for the page to load?

Comment: Use $(document).ready if you are using jQuery. If you want to do it in pure Javascript you can try using 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
});

Comment: Or do it like in my anwer! For scripts like that it's allways better to include them right before the closing body tag, so that they don't block the content from loading

Comment: but still its a good practice to wait for all the elements to be available in which event listeners are to be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script needs to be placed below the html (or be wrapped in window.onload) in order to find the elements at runtime. Also, your `addEventListener` is wrong, right now it isn't a function that gets called, but `undefined`. Try it like this:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", someFunction);

function someFunction(){
    alert(document.getElementById("number").value)
};
```

HTML:

```
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" id="number" name="number" ></input>
        <input type="button" id="button" name="button" value="Test number"></input>
    </form>
    <script src="nibble.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Created one fiddle for you. Hope this will be of some help.

http://jsfiddle.net/mfLt7/96/

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', someFunction);


function someFunction(){
 var value = document.getElementById('number').value;
 alert(value);

}

});
```

Hope this be of some help. Happy Learning

Comment: Thanks, the $(document).ready(function() will be a good practice to apply! Is there a way to do this without jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vullnetyy/382f1aso/1/) I just made. The way you are passing someFunction to your addEventListener call is wrong because you are calling the function instead of passing it's reference to the event listener so it can decide to call it on its own.

Here's what the function looks like:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", someFunction);

function someFunction(){ 
    document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = document.getElementById("number").value 
};
```